# Why doesn't Clang come with standard library headers?

Tags: c++, clang, standard-library, llvm-clang

I downloaded Clang 3.6.2 from [this website](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html) and am trying to set it up with Code::Blocks under Windows. Unfortunately, it fails to compile a simple "hello world" program on the grounds that it doesn't know where `iostream` is.

Looking through the install folder, it does not appear to include a standard library with it. Why? And how do I get it?

Comment: I had that same issue on Linux. clang++ didn't come with headers and erroneously looked at gcc installations (not g++) to try and figure out where it could find them,and then once it decided what directory it thought they were in - it never looked to see if they were actually there. I had to download a later version of g++ to match what gcc was there in order to get clang++ to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard library is NOT part of the compiler itself. It is part of the runtime environment on a particular platform. Sure, some organisations put together a "kit" with all the necessary parts to build an application - there may even be someone that packages a Clang compiler with a suitable runtime.

In general, you should be able to download the [Windows SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) and get the relevant header files there - and if you use `clang-cl`, it should be largely compatible with the MSVC compiler [or provide `clang` or `clang++` with the correct `-fms-compatibility` or whatever it is called].

Or as suggested in the other answer, use `libcxx`, but it's not 100% complete for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

They do have a c++ standard library: [libcxx.llvm.org](http://libcxx.llvm.org). But it's not fully supported on the windows platform.

Comment: Not fully supported? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Therhang, Last I heard, the exception situation (IIRC, the Structured Exception Handling side) was a difficult problem.

Comment: @Therhang: On their website, they have a list of supported platforms. It doesn't include Windows. But they do say: _"Ports to other platforms are underway. Here are recent test results for Windows and Linux."_